# Text not getting center aligned in a CSS button

Tags: html, css

```css
.button {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #012839;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  color: #00c7ec;
  border: 1px solid #00c7ec;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 199, 236, 0.5);
  background-color: #00c7ec;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.button:hover:before {
  -webkit-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  -moz-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 86%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Gallery</a>
```

I wanted to use this button in my personal project but the problem I am having is that the text in the button i.e. "Gallery" is not getting center aligned even after I put the "text-align:"center" in the button class.

Comment: change padding-left:2em.

Answer (score 2):

Because of you  define `width 50px;`  now do this

add `width: auto;` or remove `width: 50px;`

as like this

```css
.button {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #012839;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  
  color: #00c7ec;
  border: 1px solid #00c7ec;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 199, 236, 0.5);
  background-color: #00c7ec;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.button:hover:before {
  -webkit-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  -moz-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 86%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Gallery</a>
```

Comment: i do not want to remove the width as then the button's width increases a lot and it's not looking nice

Comment: sorry for this your width is 50px than can u increase your width

Answer (score 1):

Add .button { width: auto; } to get your result

Answer (score 0):

change
padding-left : 5em to 2.5em

Answer (score 0):

I had removed `padding` and added `min-width:220px`:

```css
.button {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #012839;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00c7ec;
    min-width: 220px; /*Here you can give any value other then 220px*/
    border: 1px solid #00c7ec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 3em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 199, 236, 0.5);
  background-color: #00c7ec;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.button:hover:before {
  -webkit-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  -moz-animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
  animation: shine 0.5s 0s linear;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
}
.button:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 86%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes shine {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Gallery</a>
```